# Json Deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need some help deserializing this JSON.

I'm using newtonsoft to deserialize the JSON:

This is how my JSON is looking:

```
[  
  {  
  "CUSTOMER":{  
     "CUSTOMERNO":"ABC123",
     "BUSINESSAREA":"A",
     "FIRSTNAME":"B",
     "LASTNAME":"Goos",
     "GENDER":1
  },
  "PERMISSION":[  
     {  
        "EMAIL":"bg@123.com",
        "TYPE":"ALL",
        "VALUE":1,
        "STATUS":"test",
        "DATAORIGIN":"CUBA",
        "PERMISSIONDATE":"2016-11-30 00:00:00",
        "CHANGEDATE":"2016-11-30 00:00:00"
     },
     {  
        "EMAIL":"bg@346.com",
        "TYPE":"NECC",
        "VALUE":0,
        "STATUS":"test2",
        "DATAORIGIN":"CUBA",
        "PERMISSIONDATE":"2016-10-30 00:00:00",
        "CHANGEDATE":"2016-10-30 00:00:00"
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

Here my Model:

```
public class CUSTOMER
{
    public string CUSTOMERNO { get; set; }
    public string BUSINESSAREA { get; set; }
    public string FIRSTNAME { get; set; }
    public string LASTNAME { get; set; }
    public int GENDER { get; set; }
}

public class PERMISSION
{
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }
    public string TYPE { get; set; }
    public int VALUE { get; set; }
    public string STATUS { get; set; }
    public string DATAORIGIN { get; set; }
    public string PERMISSIONDATE { get; set; }
    public string CHANGEDATE { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public CUSTOMER CUSTOMER { get; set; }
    public List<PERMISSION> PERMISSION { get; set; }
}
```

When I deserialize the JSON with this code:

```
var jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(value);
```

I'm receiving following error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'TCookRestWrapper.Models.RootObject' because the type requires a JSON
>   object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this
>   error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements
>   a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can
>   be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be
>   added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path
>   '', line 1, position 1.

I´ll appreciate any idea how to solve it.

Comment: HI volks, I was able to solve it with addiing the rootobject into a List<>                                                                                         List<RootObject> root = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jSon);

Comment: the idea is that you mark one answer from the below as accepted (in case there is one correct and/or helped you the most), so this question is marked as solved for the community.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'TCookRestWrapper.Models.RootObject' ....

Indicates that you are trying to deserialize an array to one object, more precisely `RootObject` You can clearly see that the JSON you have, starts with `[` and ends with `]`. Which means it is an array.

While the correct answer simply would be, deserialize to a type of `List<RootObject>`:

```
var jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(value);
```

#### Property Naming Guidelines

Guidelines and good practice is to name your properties by some meaning and use pascal case.

To do this when you deal with the JSON you provided is really simple and can be realized easily with attributes like in the next class.

*(Note: I changed the property name Permission to Permissions, since it can hold more the one.)*

```
public class Customer
{
    [JsonProperty("CUSTOMERNO")]
    public string CustomerNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("BUSINESSAREA")]
    public string BusinessArea { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FIRSTNAME")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LASTNAME")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("GENDER")]
    public int Gender { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    [JsonProperty("EMAIL")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TYPE")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("VALUE")]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("STATUS")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DATAORIGIN")]
    public string DataOrigin { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PERMISSIONDATE")]
    public string PermissionDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CHANGEDATE")]
    public string ChangeDate { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("CUSTOMER")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PERMISSION")]
    public List<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You having a bad day, downvoter ? *Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.* ... otherwise, you are using it the wrong way. Or an explanation would be at minimum useful.

Comment: Hi Jim,thx a lot for you suggestions, it works properly. I´ve adjusted the property names etc.. Thx!

Comment: Sorry, I was in the middle of commenting. I'm not having a bad day, more a busy day. I downvoted because your answer annotated the two answers already given. It's better to suggest edits to an answer, rather than answer again. That being said, downvoting both our answers in revenge is a direct contravention of the rules, and I've reported it as such.

Comment: ... i do realise i'm being hypocritical here, as my answer is also technically a duplicate (albeit by about 10 seconds). Hence, the deletion of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your Json string is an array of object because it starts with `[]` so you need to Deserialize it to list of `RootObject`.

```
var jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(value);
```